# How add USB device to a VirtualBox snapshot?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, snapshot, partition-recovery

I need to repair 1TB HDD I was restoring it sector by sector with the Disk Genius from thr Hirens iso file ( ofcourse in VM ) for about 24 hours.
Than I need to turn off the notebook so, I paused the VM and wait for a while and than unpaused. This was continuing normaly so I decided to pause it than to create an snapshot and than to turn off the notebook.
Another evening I wanted to continue in my HDD restoring process but after I start the VM the HDD is not mounted into the VM so the whole process crashes with reading from disk error.

So What I need is to run the VM to pause mode ( that I can add the USB device first ) and than unpause and continue.

OR

To add USB device to the Snapshot settings. ( I was trying this many times again and again but the settings window doesnt want to save my USB devices changes ) The list of the USB devices is empty !!!

Answer (score 1):

You don' unserstand my question.
I was asking that if it is possible to start the VM to paused mode.
I was not able to do it therefore I was asking here.
But in the meantime I had a tip for the DiskGenius (admin please add the TAG DiskGenius to this question )  from the hirens disk:
!!! It is possible to recover all files from the HDD also if it is formated to linux partition!!!
And you don't have to wait untill the scan will all cluster of your harddisk.
Here is a little cheat:

1. Mount the "FORMATED" HDD in settings of the USB and add USB
2. Mount the second HDD  in the settings of the USB and add USB
3. In settings of the Storage click to add CD/DVD device > In pop up message click > Choose the disk
4. Start the Virtual Machine
5. the Hirens Boot CD should automaticaly start
6. Start miniWindows XP from Hirend boot CD
7. Start the HBCD menu
8. in the Programs>>Recovery >> DiskGenius
9. Select the partition which you wanna recovery
10. Click on the recover icon
11. Choose the Recover formated patition
12. Choose filesystem before formated ( I took the NTFS )
13. Click start
14. After about 20 minutes of scanning you should get the all count of files which were on HDD
15. Than you can stop the scanning (which will take about 10 - 15 minutes so don't panic !!! )
16. So after 30 minutes you should be able to see the whole folders structure and files.
17. Just mark the folders you want recover
18. Now you can easily copy files to another disk.

hope that I helped you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you go into the VirtualBox Manager and click Settings for the VM. Then go to Ports then USB and add the device there before unpausing?